# Animation queue buildup with Galleriffic 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, image-gallery

I'm trying to figure out how to use the stop() function to stop the animation buildup that occurs with Galleriffic.  It happens when you mouse over the thumbnail images quickly and repetitively.  I know in a simple jquery script you'd use the stop() function with the animate function, but galleriffic uses so much code I'm not exactly sure where and how to apply it.

I'm new to jquery btw.  Using jQuery 1.4.4 and Galleriffic 2.0, and have been working off the examples included with the Galleriffic download.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, finally figured it out.  Turns out that the transparency fading when mousing over the thumbnails is handled by a script called "jquery.opacityrollover.js".

The transparency is not animated with the jquery "animate" function, but is instead animated with the "fadeTo" function.  The code looks like this:

```
/**
 * jQuery Opacity Rollover plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Trent Foley (http://trentacular.com)
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
;(function($) {
var defaults = {
    mouseOutOpacity:   0.67,
    mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
    fadeSpeed:         'fast',
    exemptionSelector: '.selected'
};

$.fn.opacityrollover = function(settings) {
    // Initialize the effect
    $.extend(this, defaults, settings);

    var config = this;

    function fadeTo(element, opacity) {
        var $target = $(element);

        if (config.exemptionSelector)
            $target = $target.not(config.exemptionSelector);    

        $target.fadeTo(config.fadeSpeed, opacity);
    }

    this.css('opacity', this.mouseOutOpacity)
        .hover(
            function () {
                fadeTo(this, config.mouseOverOpacity);
            },
            function () {
                fadeTo(this, config.mouseOutOpacity);
            });

    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

So I figured out through trial and testing that all you have to do is change

```
$target.fadeTo(config.fadeSpeed, opacity);
```

to

```
$target.stop().fadeTo(config.fadeSpeed, opacity);
```